# create an user in google apps using admin sdk api in java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-admin-sdk

How to create an user in google apps using admin sdk api in java.

If i use

```
    Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("DirectoryCommandLine").build();

    User qq=new User();

   qq.set("familyName",request.getParameter("familyName"));
   qq.set("givenName",request.getParameter("givenName"));
   qq.set("password",request.getParameter("password"));
   qq.set("primaryEmail",request.getParameter("primaryEmail"));
   qq.set("organizations",request.getParameter("organizations"));
Directory.Users.Insert grequest = service.users().insert(qq);
      try {
        grequest.execute();


      } catch (IOException e) {}
```

it is not inserting.

Comment: did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should output the error in your catch block, it would help a lot to debug your problem...